# jQuery combobox: standard script to catch selected value of combobox does not work

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using jqueryui combobox example at http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html

I added the script seen below to catch the selected value of combobox:

```
<div id="selectedOpt">
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#combobox").change(function() {
        var retval = $(this).val();
        $("#selectedOpt").html("retval=" + retval);
    });
});
</script>
```

However, it does not work as expected:

> 1. the div selectedOpt does not show selected value of combobox each time
>      the change event occurs
> 2. If "show underlying effect" is selected (pls try at [url above](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html)), a standard dropdown list
>      appear. When trying to change value of
>      that dropdown list, then the div
>      selectedOpt is able to show value
>      correctly.

The goal is to have `div selectedOpt` display the selected option of the combobox.
Please advise and please explain why (1) does not work while (2) works.

PS: all neccessary js, css are correctly included.
Thanks for your kind attention.

**SOLUTION FOUND:
http://robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.com/2010/09/event-handling-with-jquery-autocomplete.html**

Comment: Please use an answer to post your solution rather than updating the question. Then you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Please change your script to match the code below:

```
<script>
function test()
{ 
var retval = $("[id *=dropdown] :selected").val();
$("#selectedOpt").html("retval=" + retval);
}
</script>
```

And call this script from the server side like this:

```
dropdown.Attributes.Add("onchange","javascript: return test();")
```

Answer (score 0):

To show label or value of combobox in your div you have to include your function as an option. Something like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
 change: function(event, ui) {
  $("#selectedOpt").html("retval=" + ui.item.value);
 }
});
```

Use ui.item.label if you want a label instead.